# Exporting multiple emails using EWS Managed API

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am using EWS Managed API 2.0 and have an array of `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemId` objects i would like to export from the server. I would like to export specific email properties only to reduce bandwith usage (especially no attachments).

One way of doing this is to use the `ExchangeService.BindToItems` method with a `PropertySet`, but this method is somewhat problematic because if an error occurs for one email (for example, only html body and not text body as requested), the call fails and I haven't found a way to determine what ItemId caused the problem, so some kind of binary search is required (I'm particularly interested in the text body and not the HTML body). Also this doesn't seem the right way of doing it.

I found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/hh135142%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) that uses the ExchangeServiceBinding class and its ExportItems method, but this way I can't control what email properties are returned, and the result is not an email object, but an object that contains the email as some kind of serialized data.

What is the correct way of exporting multiple email messages using the EWS Managed API?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread over at MSDN, it addresses your questions I believe:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/6a7e2118-c3ab-46a7-b83a-74583782c3ad/exchange-web-services-managed-api-vs-webdav-performance-question

Specifically to your point regarding error handling, this was provided by David Claux, EWS Program Manager back in 2010:

> ...You are correctly using LoadPropertiesForItems, and you are correct to assume the error code in the ServiceResponse applies to the item at the same ordinal position in the collection passed to LoadPropertiesForItems...